# GPPACLPickerResources.bundle does not contain a bundle executable

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is what I get when building my app:

> ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/Impostor.app/GPPACLPickerResources.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."
>   ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/Impostor.app/GPPACLPickerResources.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

This did not happen on prior versions of GPPACLPickerResources. Here is my current Podfile pods:

```
pod 'QBFlatButton'
pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/AppInvite'
pod 'SARate'
pod 'RMStore'
```

Has anyone seen this error before or have any advice on how to report this error to Google?

Answer (score 0):

same thing here... I deleted the "Executable file" entry from Info.plist of GPPCore and resubmitted... that solved the problem... But I guess google should be warned of this issue.